# Cannot push to GitHub anymore from git via OS X terminal

Tags: git, github, terminal

Since yesterday, I cannot push anything to GitHub anymore. I get this error:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/foo/bar.git/': error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version
```

While I know that this is related to Github's [weak cryptographic standards removal](https://githubengineering.com/crypto-removal-notice/) I have no idea how to fix this issue for me, as their site (see link) only addresses how to fix this under certain clients (Windows, Red Hat) that I am not using. My environment:

OS X 10.8.5, git 2.2.1, OS X's Terminal v2.3

I don't quite know how my git was set up in my environment, as I set it up, when I just started out with git and had no idea what I was doing and I never changed it after that, as it always worked until now. Until now, to push, I just used the command `git push`, nothing else.

Does anyone know how I can set up my git environment now, so I can push again? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on a *very* dated OS/X. Given that you're probably not interested in upgrading OS/X, your only option might be to get a new version of OpenSSL and a new git compiled against it.

Does homebrew work on OS/X 10.8? Maybe MacPorts? One of those might give you more recent versions, otherwise you might have to manually compile these packages.

Comment: I have homebrew set up under OS X 10.8, which works just fine. Does that mean I have to update OpenSSL via homebrew? And then how do I "compile a new git against it"?

Comment: If you have homebrew running, try upgrading openssl and git to their latest version. homebrew has both packages, so there should be no further compiling needed.

Comment: I upgraded them both (OpenSSL to 1.0.2m, git to 2.15.0). In Terminal they still showed up in their old version. Maybe it's not linked to the brew versions? I have now linked git via `brew link --overwrite git` which worked, but openssl does not work. Error:

Warning: Refusing to link: openssl
Linking keg-only openssl means you may end up linking against the insecure, deprecated system OpenSSL while using the headers from Homebrew's openssl.
Instead, pass the full include/library paths to your compiler e.g.:
  -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib

What can I do?

Comment: Not sure, but at this point I would try opening a github issue in the homebrew project. Also, have you considered upgrading your OS/X to something a little bit more recent? I think you're at least 6 years behind?

Comment: I realized now that upgrading git to 2.15.0 alone seems to have fixed the issue. Now I can push again just like before. So the answer would be to just upgrade git via homebrew and make sure terminal is linked to this newest version. Thanks!